# R: ggplot2 and loop with data.table

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, data.table

I have to make 4 plots which differ only for `y` and `ylab`.
I start from a `data.table` `dt` which is

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(a = rnorm(20),
                 b = rnorm(20), 
                 c = rnorm(20), 
                 d = rnorm(20), 
                 e = rnorm(20))
```

Every single plot should be a scatterplot with row numbers as `x` vs `y` values. Additionally, I want to plot some `hline` at `median(y) + h*mad(y)` where `h = c(0, -2, 2, -3, 3)`

This plot should be repeated for columns `a`, `c`, `d` and `e` of `dt`.

I came up with this bit of code

```
# Defining y labels #
ylabels <- c(bquote(phantom(.)^100*A~"/"*phantom(.)^200*A),
             bquote(phantom(.)^101*C~"/"*phantom(.)^201*B),
             bquote(phantom(.)^102*D~"/"*phantom(.)^202*D),
             bquote(phantom(.)^103*E~"/"*phantom(.)^202*E))

# Selecting columns of dt    
ydata <- names(dt)[c(1, 3, 4, 5)]


h <- c(0, -2, 2, -3, 3)
hcol <- c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#E69F00", "red", "red")

# The for cycle should create the 4 plots and assign them to a list 
plots <- list()
for (i in seq_along(ydata)) {

    p1 <- ggplot(dt, aes_string(x = seq(1, dt[, .N]), y = ydata[i])) +
                     geom_point() +
                     geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept = median(ydata[i]) + 
                                       h * mad(ydata[i])), color = hcol) +
                     xlab("Replicate") + 
                     ylab(ylabels[i]) +
                     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, dt[,.N])))

     plots[[i]] <- p1  # add each plot into plot list
     }
```

Then `plots` will be fed to the `multiplot` function from [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/).

However my `loop` doesn't work properly because it fails to calculate the median and mad values.
Do you have any suggestions to make the code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# data.table with the median +- h* mad values
hline.values <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) median(x) + h * mad(x)),
                   .SDcols = ydata]

# new empty list
plots <- list()

for (i in seq_along(ydata)) {

       p1 <- ggplot(dt, aes_string(x = seq(1, dt[, .N]), y = ydata[i])) +
             geom_point() +
             geom_hline(data = hline.values, 
                        aes_string(yintercept = ydata[i])) +
             # Axis labels and theme
             xlab("Replicate") +
             ylab(ylabels[[i]]) +
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, dt[, .N]))

        plots[[i]] <- p1
}
```